# How to make msi installer automatically run included .exe file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, post-build-event

I have added an external .exe file into my VS2010 setup project and I'd like the installer to run it automatically at the end of the installation.

I am trying to use Post-build event, and put command line there, like `$(OutDir)program.exe`. But it didn't seem to work. So what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's a post-*build* event, which means it will run after you build the MSI. This has nothing at all to do with how the MSI is executed and what it does.

Comment: thx for clearing that up Joey. I think I know I should really be doing. I probably need to add it to prerequisites and run it before the installation

Comment: You have to modify the MSI file by adding a *custom action* which will execute your exe. Visual Studio has poor support for custom actions. But it's defenitely not a *Post-build event*, which is part of the IDE rather than MSI.

Comment: Thx for nice comments, Alexey. Still a lot stuff to learn for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, for launching a file installed by the package a custom action is used. You can add one in VS too. In your case, for the EXE to be launched as late as possible you can add it under the Commit phase.

Comment: I will definitely give it a shot.